# In Azure DevOps, my ECR push image task fails after a few tries with no insight

Tags: docker, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, amazon-ecr

```
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build an image
  inputs:
    command: build
    repository: weather-update-project
    dockerfile: '**/Dockerfile'
    buildContext: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    tags: 'latest'

- task: ECRPushImage@1
  inputs:
    awsCredentials: 'weather'
    regionName: us-west-2
    imageSource: 'imagename'
    sourceImageName: 'weather-update-project'
    sourceImageTag: 'latest'
    pushTag: 'latest'
    repositoryName: 'weather-update-project'
```

I'm building an image and then trying to push that image to ECR. When it gets to the ECR push image task, it tries to push a few times and then gives me the error "The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1" and that's it. There's no other information in my logs in regards to the error like there normally is. What is possibly happening? My ECR is public and all of my credentials are correct. Here's my YAML code for the docker build and ecrpushimage tasks in Azure DevOps

My Repository name that contains my dockerfile is 'weather-update-project' and my ECR repository also has the name 'weather-update-project'

Answer (score 0):

Can you please validate on what agent this is running on & if Docker is there or not?
Is the image being created properly?

While executing the ECRPushImage task at the beginning it should show at least the configuration log like below, if not then it is related to docker on that agent.

```
Configuring credentials for task
...configuring AWS credentials from service endpoint 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
...endpoint defines standard access/secret key credentials
Configuring region for task
...configured to use region us-east-1, defined in tas
```